# Is it possible to run video over type-C smartphones?

Tags: usb, video, external-display, video-streaming, samsung-gear-vr

Is it possible to run a video from a PC (over type-c, hdmi, or displayport) to a type-c smartphone for VR? What limitations would be faced?

Answer (score 1):

If your PC happens to have a WiFi adapter, you don't need to care about the connection type and can stream video content to your device via an application like [Plex](https://www.plex.tv/apps/mobile/android/) or [Moon VR Player](https://www.oculus.com/experiences/gear-vr/945657588886188/) for example.

The limitations are inherent to the video player you choose to use on your phone.

I assume you are interested by VR headsets since you included the tage "samsung-gear-vr".
For Plex for example, there is currently no native support for Gear VR, so you have to access the web interface by Oculus browser or Samsung Internet browser (it also seems to be [supported by PhoneCast](https://www.oculus.com/experiences/gear-vr/1239896026125279/)). You can also use a more complex setup such as the one described in [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/GearVR/comments/3z299a/perfect_plex_experience_on_gear_vr/).

Comment: A wired connection would decrease latency and increase bandwidth dramatically

Comment: Wired and wireless certainly both have their advantages and inconvenients. Personally I like to be able to use the headset while moving "freely", without having to connect it to some cables.

Comment: The phone wouldn't have spacial tracking, just rotational, so it isn't like I'd be moving around a lot. A thin and light type-c cable would decrease (if not get rid of) compression artifacts.

Comment: Sure. Personally I don't notice those artifacts on my device, but it depends on several things, the type of content, your Wi-Fi router, resolution on your phone and the software used. I also only watch movies or series, maybe artifacts are indeed more noticeable if you're trying to stream a 60 fps VR game. It is worth trying to see if you can accept this level of compression.